# Why is the Task Manager Total Physical Memory not 2048 MB or 2 GB

Tags: command-line, memory, cpu, task-manager

I found 3 numbers for the Total Physical Memory:

1. In the Task Manager under the Performance tab: 1978 MB
2. In Computer Properties: 2 GB
3. And running `wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory /format:list` in the command line: 2074554368 Bites

Number 1 matches Number 3 except Number 1 is rounded. When I convert Number 3 to GB `2074554368 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024` I don't quite get 2 GB. I get 1.93207932 GB.

Why does Number 1 and Number 3 not match Number 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess..

1. Task Manager is showing you memory available for programs (your address space must also include addresses that map in to other devices with memory, like your video card - memory not available to run programs within
2. I bet "Computer Properties" just rounds up/down to give a "simple" answer, you know, because that'd be "user friendly".
3. (2074554368.0/1024)/1024 = 1978.44921875

Comment: Plus 1 for this one.  Plus Windows isn't the only one giving memory.  The BIOS can also allocate memory at bootup.